# Why does \extracolsep{\fill} not fill?

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

When using `\extracolsep{\fill}` to stretch out a sparse table to the full text width, inserting multicolumns whose text is “too long” breaks the filling.

Naïvely I would have expected the second row in both tables in the example below to look the same.

Why does that happen and what can I do about it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Some text} \\
    \hline
    Left & Right \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Some longer text with spaces} \\
    \hline
    Left & Right \\
    \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably related: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/37

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the table is first set as if for a tabular, so the long spanning entry forces the second column to be wider (so `Right` no longer fills the full width of that column and does not reach its right hand edge as it is a `c` column.) then after that alignment is done, because the natural width of the table is less than `\linewidth`, `\extracolsep` (that is `\tabskip` glue) is used to separate the columns but the column widths are already fixed.

You could use

```
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\makebox[0pt]{Some longer text with spaces}}
```

to hide the width, so long as you know it will fit within the specified width and won't overshoot the page.

Comment: Do you reckon this is a bug? (either code or documentation)  This is certainly unexpected behaviour.

Comment: it is the low level behaviour of halign so hard to avoid  I think we mention it on the latex companion at least
t also other answers on this site @henr

Comment: @HenriMenke see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1090+%5Cextracolsep+minus  for an alternative setting of extracolsep that  avoids this problem